# What is the best way to represent related models in Qt?

Tags: qt, model-view

I have a Qt application built on top of a library that manages an SQL database.  I have several models (QAbstractTableModel and QAbstractListModel subclasses) that represent different tables in the database, and I have a few associated views.

The models typically have a cache of data from the database and a pointer to a database object that they can use to refresh their caches as needed.  I have implemented insertRows, removeRows, and setData so that they attempt the database operation in a transaction, and then if it succeeds, they update the cache inside beginInsertRows()/endInsertRows() (or remove as the case may be) so that the cache doesn't change outside of the begin/end pairs and everything stays in sync.

So far, so good, and everything is working fine.  If all changes to the database came from the GUI, I'd think this was a nice solution.

The problem is that some database operations involve changing tables that are represented by more than one model.  To the application, it looks like table updates that originate in the database layer.  I could have the database layer call up into the model layer whenever it wants to make a change (which is what I'm doing now), but I don't like the way it exposes the lower-level database layer to Qt models.  It also has the problem that the models need to make their changes inside a transaction so they know when the operations succeed or fail, and going through the model layer would preclude the database layer from enclosing multiple updates in a transaction.

Alternatively, I could make the caches in the models be the "real" data.  I could then change the underlying database and inform the models after the fact, at which point they would update their caches.  I think this works fine for small tables, but since it would mean caching the entire table, I don't think it works for large tables.

My thought is that this is a common enough problem that may be some kind of known best practice for this.  Is that the case?

Thanks.

Comment: What you describing is pretty much like `QSqlQueryModel` or `QSqlTableModel`. Have you considered using them instead of your own implementation? However, they doesn't have update mechanism either. You don't need to expose database layer to models. For example, you can send a signal when something is changed in the database and connect this signal to models' slots that update them.

Comment: I'm not using the Qt built-in Sql classes only because I already have a library that manages the database (so non-Qt programs don't replicate the code).  Isn't the problem with a signal that by the time the database layer does it's modification, it's too late to call beginInsertRows/beginRemoveRows/etc.?